# systemd-shim Doesn't Remove after rename this file org.freedesktop.systemd1.s‌​ervice.bak

Tags: dpkg

```
Removing systemd-shim (6-2bzr1) ... 
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: old-conffile 'debian/systemd-shim/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.systemd1.conf' is not an absolute path
dpkg: error processing package systemd-shim (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: old-conffile 'debian/systemd-shim/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.systemd1.conf' is not an absolute path
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd-shim
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here below the mess situation

---

```
'like_so_'sudo dpkg -s systemd-shim
Package: systemd-shim
Status: deinstall ok half-configured
Priority: extra
Section: admin
Installed-Size: 80
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: armhf
Version: 6-2bzr1
Config-Version: 6-2bzr1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3)
Suggests: pm-utils
Conffiles:
 /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.systemd-shim.conf 8a52da330180c68389673f0301890ad4
Description: shim for systemd
 This package emulates the systemd function that are required to run
 the systemd helpers without using the init service
Original-Maintainer: Steve Langasek <vorlon@debian.org>
```

How do I continue my `apt-get dist-update -f`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. My solution is similar to presented here http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/

I had to remove systemd-shim package entry from `/var/lib/dpkg/status`

After that `sudo apt-get install -f` started working